# Servlet not Redirected to Page, Showing Non Styled Page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

I have problem using servlet in jsp. Let say I want to get value from dropdown list and process it to servlet.

The method for process the code from the dropdown list is called **ListDetailPesanan(Pesanan p);**

I have successfully get the list from the function ListDetailPesanan which return Array List. Then the function is placed in my servlet called **submitAppPesanan** which executed from a form then redirected to page called **apesanan.jsp**

This is the servlet submitAppPesanan.java (I had place this servlet to web.xml)

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    try {
        /* GETTING VALUE FROM FORM. */
        int kode = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("kode_pesanan_tmp"));
        /* Initialize value to object */
        Pesanan p = new Pesanan(kode);
        /* execute the object to gain result set */
        MasterPesanan mp = new MasterPesanan();
        List<Pesanan> psn = mp.ListDetailPesanan(p);
        java.lang.System.out.println("Pesanan " + psn);
        /* sending result set to apesanan.jsp again */
        if(psn != null){
            request.setAttribute("listpesanan", psn);
            request.getRequestDispatcher("system/apesanan.jsp").forward(request, response);
        }     
    } catch(Exception e) {
        java.lang.System.out.println("Exception on Submit App Pesanan " + e.getMessage() + "\n" + e.getCause()); 
    } finally {            
        java.lang.System.out.println("Submit Kode Pesanan Successfully Executed");
    }
}
```

but the servlet is not redirect again to apesanan.jsp, but the servlet stays in the page and showing non-styled page of apesanan.jsp.

1. What's wrong with this code? because i see the output result from my
   Glassfish Server nothing error.
2. How properly consume the list from servlet to apesanan.jsp page?

thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

Screenshot from my apesanan.jsp page then executed the servlet.

[image: Original apesanan.jsp]

then the redirection then stacked here.

[image: servlet redirection]

**UPDATE**

The result list is working properly and shown as i want, but still no clue what's going on.

[image: result printed]

Comment: why down vote for this question?

Comment: Good question, would you got any exception?

Comment: @Masud, none. There isn't any exception printed. I have tracked the jsp page, servlet and function to get the result list. The result list is catched (Pesanan [objects.Pesanan@1d6c08f, objects.Pesanan@1fc153c, objects.Pesanan@d6247e])

Comment: Are you sure that is is not forwarding to the jsp page. I am asking this because, it is same jsp you are forwarding to. Did you tried accessing the list in the jsp page?

Comment: @ABP yes, it's executed the servlet, but only stacked on servlet page. please see my UPDATE section. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your css are not loaded because i guess that you are using relative path like 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/theme.css">` in your jsp.

When you forward the request to a jsp page the page URL won't change because of this the relative path wont resolve to the css files.

Use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%=request.getcontextpath()%>/css/theme.css">` or JSTL's c:url tag.

Comment: yes, the style is working now, but still the page is not redirected but still stay at the servlet page. anyway, do you know how to create clickable url in JSTL?

Comment: JSTL dont have any link tag but you can use jstl to create href property in an anchor tag like ```<a href="<c:url value="/jsp/index.htm"/>">TEST</a>```. Refer http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your path In RequestDispatcher.

try something Like ("/system/apesanan.jsp");